# Apache2 : How to remove port from URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache2

I have the following apache configuration file for a reverse proxy :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName https://www.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/NewPC-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/NewPC-access.log common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2    
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The reverse proxy works properly but I always have the port number (5000) in the URL.

The reverse proxy should redirect requests from internet to an internal local application accessible from localhost:5000. The internal application is correctly exposed to internet but the url has always the port shown like : example.com:5000

Is there any way to remove it please ?

Regards,

Comment: Reconfigure the web application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how to do that please ?

Comment: You say that the application is correctly exposed to the internet. Why don't you configure the proxy to redirect requests to the correct internet URL?

Comment: I can't advise you how to configure your web application because you didn't say what it is!

Comment: Apache configuration looks good. Can you share snapshot - how your are getting port in the URL.